# Cannot find module '../build/Release/magic' from 'index.js' during Jest tests

Tags: typescript, jestjs, mmmagic

I have the following error, while running jest tests:

Cannot find module '../build/Release/magic' from 'index.js'

```
  at Resolver.resolveModule (node_modules/jest-resolve/build/index.js:191:17)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/mmmagic/lib/index.js:3:13)
```

If I run an app as normal, it works without problems, but when trying to run Jest tests throws error above. Maybe someone has a similar issue. Thank you.

NodeJS: **8.11**,

default_configuration: **'Release'**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

mmmagic in `build/Resolve/magic` imports file magic.node, but Jest only imports files with extensions that specified in `moduleFileExtensions`. So solution is simple, just add `node` to `moduleFileExtensions`:

```
"moduleFileExtensions": [
    "js",
    "json",
    "ts",
    "node"
],
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused about where you put this?

Comment: @MysticSeagull you have to put this in jest.config.js or wherever you have your jest configuration